# Finding the labels of a shuffled pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, labeling

I have a dataframe (namely *'original'*) with over a thousand numerical columns as features and one label column. I also have a shuffled version of the same dataframe (namely *'shuffled'*) with label column dropped. The question is, how to assign the correct labels to the second dataframe? I came up a with a ridiculous code that works, but surely there must be a simple straightforward way?

```
original.drop('label', axis = 1, inplace = True)

dic = dict()
for i in range(100000):
    dic[str(original.loc[i].tolist())] = label[i]

shuffled_labels = np.zeros(100000)
for i in range(100000):
    shuffled_labels[i] = dic[str(shuffled.loc[i].tolist())]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should index the `original` dataframe by the `shuffled` one, as follows:

```py
shuffled_labels = original.iloc[shuffled.index]['label']
shuffled_labels
```

Comment: Unfortunately this code provided a wrong answer.

Comment: @asmani Probably depends on the way you obtain the `shuffled` dataset, you perform the shuffling using pandas? I ask because if the `shuffled` dataset has been re-indexed (i.e., by resetting the indices) then my answer won't work.

Comment: Yes, the shuffled dataset has been re-indexed, and that made it a challenge for me.